# CSS Hover+Background Image

Tags: css, hover, background-image, doctype

I'm creating a special UI control using HTML/CSS to mimic the Windows 7 Control Panel buttons. So far, I've got the layout right and now I'd like to add some cosmetics to it.

As seen here, there is a gradient that appears when you hover over the button with your mouse.

http://m.cncfps.com/zack/files/this-control.png

Now, you can see [here](http://toro.azwestern.edu/~zbl/w7controls.html) that I've got the layout done. I'd like to add a `:hover` effect to the whole div item with a background image.

Currently, here is what I have for the CSS- yet it doesn't work. No image shows up in IE8, or FireFox

**EDIT:** It works in Chrome, but not in FireFox or IE.

```
#cp .cp-item:hover
{
    background:url(images/hoverbg.png) repeat-x;
}
```

It does however work with a `background-color` rather than an image.

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? If so, does hoverbg.png exists within the images folder? Theres nothing wrong with the sintax I believe.

Comment: It's important to note that IE only supports the :hover pseudo selector for <a> tags.

Comment: I think you only can user :hover with Tag "a". are you using it?

Comment: @user194076 - Yea, I just noticed that after a friend told me it did work in Chrome. I was viewing it personally through a VNC console so the colors didn't indicate it working.

Comment: @Zack and @thirtydot, can you add the CSS "hover" selector for anything? or just a certain set of html items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- There's nothing (relevant) wrong with your CSS.
- The path to your image is correct.

It already works in Chrome.

Chrome seems to be more intelligent (or lenient) than other browsers. If I inspect the page, it's inserting stuff:

[image]

It doesn't work in other browsers because you don't have a proper page structure (no doctype, no `<html>` tag, no `<body>` tag, etc) - your page [doesn't validate](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftoro.azwestern.edu%2F~zbl%2Fderp.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), and the other browsers do not "like it". I don't know the exact reason *why* it doesn't work with the other browsers - I imagine the reason is either an implementation detail, or buried within the W3 spec.

This works in "all browsers":

[***Live Demo***](http://jsbin.com/uxepo4)
*(I'm using the `<base>` tag to make the paths work)*

It's your exact code, wrapped in typical boilerplate, with the addition of the `<base>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<base href="http://toro.azwestern.edu/~zbl/" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

<div id="cp">
    <div class="cp-item"><span>
        <div class="cp-item-icon"><img src="images/syssec.png" title="System and Security" /></div>
        <div class="cp-item-content">
            <h4>System and Security</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </span></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aha. That would most likely be why. I didn't add doctypes because I was just creating it and then I was going to move it to my main project when I had it done and created. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) You might want to use the HTML5 doctype instead. Dreamweaver surprised me with the XHTML doctype (Thanks, Dreamweaver!)

Comment: doctype isn't being specified by me. It's being specified by WordPress; specifically the admin area. So, whatever that is, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

try to change the `#cp .cp-item:hover` to `#cp div.cp-item:hover`