# How can I get :hover state for jCarousel arrows to work?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, doctype, jcarousel

I'm using the jQuery "jCarousel" plugin to create a carousel of NFL player photos. Everything works great, except the next/previous arrows in the carousel. They don't respond to the CSS rules I created for their :hover states.

Here's a single example page with the HTML and CSS: http://www.joshrenaud.com/pd/picks/jCarouselProblem.html

The style rule for the arrow works fine:

```
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal {
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 135px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent url(graphics/right-arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    }
```

But the style rule for the hover state does not:

```
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    }
```

I tried using Firebug to figure out what's up, but I'm still coming up empty. It shows me that it knows about the :hover styles for the list elements. But when I inspect the arrows, it's as if the :hover rules don't apply to those elements.

Comment: It works for me fine. Are you testing in IE6?

Comment: No, I was testing in Firefox 4. 

EDIT: After reading your comment, I checked other browsers. It worked correctly in Safari and Chrome, but not Firefox 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you haven't included the typical boilerplate HTML. Your page is rendering in [Quirks Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Quirks_Mode_Behavior).

If you add something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and slot the rest of your code where it should go, it will work.

---

Here's a previous answer I wrote where the problem was the same thing:

[CSS Hover+Background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097234/css-hoverbackground-image/5097367#5097367)

Comment: You are right. I am such an idiot. Any idea why the other hover states worked okay (on the list items)?

Comment: The reason is within that document I linked to: In Firefox "Quirks Mode" `The :hover pseudoclass will only be applied to links, images, and form controls, unless the selector includes tag names, ids, or attributes.`.

Comment: Indeed, Alex. Thanks guys for your help.